# NFS Server: Not starting: portmapper is not running

Tags: raspbian, nfs

I'm attempting to set up my Raspberry Pi with Wheezy Raspbian 2013-02-09 as an NFS server (client will be Ubuntu 12.10). I have followed [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo#NFS_Server).

I can't start the service and get the following message:

```
$ sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart
[ ok ] Stopping NFS kernel daemon: mountd nfsd.
[ ok ] Unexporting directories for NFS kernel daemon....
[ ok ]   Exporting directories for NFS kernel daemon....
[....] Starting NFS kernel daemon: nfsd
[warn] Not starting: portmapper is not running ... (warning).
$ rpcinfo -p
<br>rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: RPC: Remote system error - No such file or directory
```

Not sure what is missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A moderator in [this forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=12131&p=412731) said that this command would work:

```
sudo update-rc.d rpcbind enable && sudo update-rc.d nfs-common enable
```

Comment: confirmed as a working solution. with an eye towards the move to systemd equivalent command is `sudo systemctl enable rpcbind && sudo systemctl enable nfs-common` (although both of these services do appear to still use  init.d style startup).

Comment: i think i also needed to explicitly start the services, and that ordering was important with nfs-common needing to be 1st. i used `sudo systemctl start nfs-common` then `sudo systemctl start rpcbind`

Answer (score 10):

I had to restart rpcbind service to work:

> $ sudo service rpcbind restart

I've found it out in [this thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=12131&p=412731)

Comment: You somehow didn't link to the thread, I've fixed it for you. Glad to see new users involved! Also, pop into the chat from time to time and stay a bit, it's always nice to have someone new to talk to :D

Comment: This made NFS work for me not the other answer.

Answer (score 8):

```
$ sudo service rpcbind restart
```

...does work, but the "portmapper is not running" problem will reappear on the next reboot.

The bottom of [this page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/TCF/Raspberry_Pi) has a fix that will survive a reboot, but be aware it will delete your /etc/exports.  In short, backup your /etc/exports then:

```
sudo apt-get purge rpcbind
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
```

Then restore your /etc/exports.

Comment: using your answer combined with this:  http://www.pihomeserver.fr/en/2013/06/21/raspberry-pi-home-server-utiliser-votre-systeme-sur-nfs/  did the trick for me.

Comment: This solved for me. For some reason the NFS kernel server was wrongly installed. Thanks.

Comment: I've seen the same sort of issues on other Debian distros (I run them on my Home PCs) - somehow `rpcbind` is the replacement for `portmapper` but the aliasing does not seem to have been completed (or it is a superficial issue masking a deeper one!) Also, I run a `systemd` free household - so faulty `init.d` scripts are likely for me to have issues with.

Answer (score 6):

I am running Raspbian Jessie Lite (released on Mar 18, 2016), and got the same issue. Here is my steps to completely fix this issue, **even if after a reboot**.

Firstly have a look at the init file for `/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server`, you should notice its start runlevel is **2,3,4,5**.

Also look at the following files' start runlevel, which is **S** only. I changed its runlevel to **2,3,4,5**.

```
/etc/init.d/nfs-common
/etc/init.d/rpcbind
```

Then try to `update-rc.d` the changed init scripts with **defaults**. First try fails. **The trick is to remove and add them again.**

```
update-rc.d -f rpcbind remove
update-rc.d rpcbind defaults

update-rc.d -f nfs-common remove
update-rc.d nfs-common defaults

update-rc.d -f nfs-kernel-server remove
update-rc.d nfs-kernel-server defaults
```

After that, check the order of the services. It should be `rpcbind`, `nfs-common`, and `nfs-kernel-server`.

I also posted a blog for this. You can also find it [here](http://lesca.me/archives/debian-or-raspbian-nfs-kernel-server-not-starting-portmapper-is-not-running.html).

Comment: After months of attempting to fix this through various other means, I'd resigned myself to manually restarting NFS at boot.  This solution works.  Thank you!

Comment: This is THE fix. All the other ones posted did not fix the problem. Thank you very much for posting this!

Answer (score 2):

The underlying problem is the symlinks in /etc/rc*.d are scattered around a bit. Some of the suggestions above rely on remaking these links and, perhaps, they get made with more appropriate order. Sometimes. Try -

```
for i in rpcbind nfs-common nfs-kernel-server ; do find /etc/rc* -name "S*$i*"; done
```

to see when they are started. In reality, you only need them started at level 3, so I edited /etc/init.d/rcpbind, /etc/init.d/nfs-common and /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server so "# Default-Start: 3" and ran this to enforce it -

```
for i in rpcbind nfs-common nfs-kernel-server ; do update-rc.d -f "$i" remove; update-rc.d "$i" defaults; done
```

Note  that update-rc.d will not change an existing entry and silently fails to remove an entry (if script still exists) unless you add the -f.
Ideally you will end up with something like this -

```
/etc/rc3.d/S01rpcbind
/etc/rc3.d/S02nfs-common
/etc/rc3.d/S03nfs-kernel-server
```

And it will now boot cleanly. An update to NFS may well overwrite your good work...

Comment: This is the best answer IMHO. Gives a direct approach understanding the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue as well. The above solutions didn't work.
In my case it came from an **issue with my locales**. The following line popped up in the terminal during installation of: `nfs-kernel-server nfs-common rpcbind`.

> perl: warning: Setting locale failed.

Make sure you don't see an error about your **locales** during the installation of these packages. I fixed my locales, reinstalled the packages and now it works.

Comment: It does seem possible to me that the installing those packages *twice* may have fixed the issue anyhow, rather than sorting out your locales - though of course that is a good thing to have straightened out anyhow!

Comment: I agree. Anyhow, after fixing the locales the second installation looked way more safe without all the errors.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Clean and resists reboots.

You have to setup systemd to do the order properly

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/systemd/system/nfs-common.services
[Unit]
Description=NFS Common daemons
Wants=remote-fs-pre.target
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nfs-common start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/nfs-common stop

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
EOF

cat <<EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/systemd/system/rpcbind.service
[Unit]
Description=RPC bind portmap service
After=systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
Wants=remote-fs-pre.target
Before=remote-fs-pre.target
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/rpcbind -f -w
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
Alias=portmap
EOF

sudo systemctl enable nfs-common
sudo systemctl enable rpcbind
sudo reboot
```

taken from here

https://github.com/geerlingguy/raspberry-pi-dramble/issues/65#issuecomment-283046966

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with:
$ sudo service portmap start
Then restart nfs service:
$ sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested most of the previous solutions, they don't work after a restart of the Raspberry Pi ( the command `rpcinfo -p | grep nfs` gave me nothing ).

Solution :

```
echo service nfs-kernel-server restart | sudo tee -a /etc/rc.local
```

or

```
sudo vi /etc/rc.local
```

> ```
> service nfs-kernel-server restart
> ```

To verify :

```
> sudo shutdown -r now

> rpcinfo -p | grep nfs
```

*Tested on Raspian 8 (jessie)*